# Is it possible to put/get objects in Azure Dedicated Cache using console application

Tags: azure, azure-caching

Could someone please confirm whether it's possible to make user of Azure Dedicated Cache using normal console application OR it should be the azure project?

Comment: By Dedicated Cache, do you mean "In Role Cache" or "Windows Azure Caching Service" (which is in Preview currently)? Sorry about such dumb question but terminology is confusing :)

Comment: Yep, azure In Role Dedicated Cache.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `In Role` caching, then it would only work from within your roles that too within the roles in your cloud service. You can't use `In Role` cache outside of your roles.

If you want your cache to be accessible from outside of your roles, you may want to look into [`Windows Azure Caching Service`](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/cache/) which is in preview currently. From whatever documentation I have read about it, my understanding is that this cache can be shared among various cloud resources (Cloud Services, Web Sites, VM etc.). Going by that, I would assume that this cache should be available to your console application also. Check out this blog post from Scott Guthrie: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/09/03/windows-azure-new-distributed-dedicated-high-performance-cache-service-more-cool-improvements.aspx.

Comment: New Caching service is accessible from outside the role

Answer (score 0):

You can have a console app for development purposes, but if you want to access with a decent latency, you would anyway have to use cloud.